# Weird artifacts after rotating with scipy ndimage.rotate (values above 1.0)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, rotation, scipy

I am trying to rotate an image with the ndimage.rotate routine from the scipy module. It works fine but my RGB image has pixel values bigger than one after applying the routine.See the image after the routine here:

[image: The rotated image]
[image: These values are above 1, maximum is 1.03607709928]

Further information about the input:
This is from the default image from where I crop this smaller part. The first value is the maximum pixel value in the image, then the shape and type.

> 1.0 (1944, 2592, 3)

Same for the cropped  (unrotated) iamge:

> 1.0 (228, 554, 3)

And for the rotated one:

> 1.03607709928 (330, 587, 3)

The function call is the following, just before printing the third set of the above values. Should be fine I guess, at least I get the desired output apart from the artifacts.

```
rotated_rctgl = ndi.rotate(img[min_short:max_short, min_long:max_long], thetalst[ln_nbrs_of_rect[selected_r][0]] * rad_deg)
```

I have not found anything on that topic, is there a bug or am I using the routine in a wrong fashion? Can anyone help with this, would be quite interesting to me!
Cheers!

Comment: can you upload the original image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid overshoot in the interpolation performed by [`rotate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html), use `order=1`.

(The same behavior has been reported in a scipy [issue on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5925).)

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer!